# How to add location url in Wordpress(Appearance --> Menu --> URL)?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on WP site which is currently having this kind of testing instace url:  http://someipaddress/~directory/directory/ and then "wp-admin"

now If I want to link of any page in top navigation through wp-admin--> Appearance --> Menu

I need to use "/~directory/directory/" in URL field(THIS IS WHAT THE PROBLEM IS)

[image: /~directory/directory/]

Now I've to move it on production instance, and it has different kind of url like : "http://mywpsite.com/", so again I need to change this URL over there.

Does anyone has any idea how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) page of the Codex, specifically the "[Changing Your Domain Name and URLs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Changing_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs)" section.  In essence, the easiest way is to update the database directly (back it up first, of course), using something like the [Search and Replace script for WordPress](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/), which'll handle things like serialized values in the database for you.

Answer (score 0):

What about changing url structure by a query

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
```

Comment: That _might_ work if you're lucky, but anywhere the data is [PHP-serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), you'll break the serialization, and WordPress won't be able to use it (serialized data contains string lengths, which would change in the OP's case).  I speak from experience :(

Comment: It works as per changing the siteurl in database, i have checked it and i never got  any problem while using this queries to update the urls. may be you got problem but i never had any.

Comment: Changing the siteurl, sure - that value's not serialized.  But (to pick one of the other tables you're updating) if `wp_postmeta` has a serialized metavalue, you'll break the serialization, and PHP won't be able to use the value.